# RS422 interfacing with the Arduino

Tags: serial, sensors

Good day,
I have a sensor which supports serial data output using RS422 which has 4 wires (RX+, RX-, TX+, TX-)
my question is how can I connect this sensor to the Arduino.
I read that i can use 2 max485 chips to do this but uncertain of the exact procedure.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not really an arduino question, for of an Electrical Engineering question,    this should help   https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/280073/how-to-interface-rs-422-to-uart-on-my-mcu

Answer (score 1):

There are pre-made and very inexpensive Arduino RS-485 modules available on Ebay or Amazon.  Much simpler than building your own circuit.

They look like this:

[image: RS-485 Module]

Answer (score 0):

The MAX490 chip consists of DI (pin 3) and RO (pin 2) pins that connect to the Arduino TX and RX respectively. the rs-422 side of the chip consists of pin 5 (Y / T+), Pin 6 (Z / T-), pin 7 (B / R-) and pin 8 (A / R+)

http://arduinotronics.blogspot.com/2018/09/long-distance-serial-with-rs-422.html